# How to make errorbars with perpendicular line ends in octave

Tags: octave, errorbar

I have a question about errorbar in octave. I'm trying to plot my measure results in a plot with:

errorbar(m, my,ex, '>d')

It shows nearly what I want, except one thing, but please for the nearly description at the picture in the appendix[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afMTR.jpg)

I would like to have the errorbars with the perpendicular lines at the line ends
like at this picture:
https://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/advisor/advisor5/images/h4r3.gif

Can someone give a hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I type this in octave:

```
x = 1:10;
y = x.^2;
mx = (x/1.5).^-1;
errorbar (x,y,mx,'>d')
axis([-1,10,0,100]);
```

I get this:
[image]
Just like the picture you wanted. I don't get the angle brackets like you're getting.

**EDIT: If what you're asking is for *taller* bars**, you can do this with the following "hack":

```
c = get(gca,'children'); c = get(c,'children')(2);
ydata = get(c,'ydata');
ydata(4:9:end) = ydata(4:9:end) - 5;  % '5' is the value to raise by
ydata(5:9:end) = ydata(5:9:end) + 5;
ydata(7:9:end) = ydata(7:9:end) - 5;
ydata(8:9:end) = ydata(8:9:end) + 5;
set(c,'ydata',ydata)
```

[image]

Comment: note: I used `get(gca,'children')` because this was the only plot on my workspace. It is safer to collect the handle of your errorbar plot into a variable and use that instead, i.e. `h = errorbar(<bla bla>)`, then `c = get(h,'children')`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! I tried only your first code and get the same result. I dont understand why it dont go at my code <br/> a

Comment: I would like to post my code, but i cant it make as a code block.

Comment: @Perilun update your question with it. To insert a "code block" simply add 4 spaces in front of each line, and make sure there is empty space on top and below the code block, separating it from the surrounding text.